# How to display data in textbox from mysql database based on the selected option in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have a Project List dropdown option that I get from the database (MySQL select query). In the database, the Project List table has a Client Name column. I want to show the Client Name in the text box when I select a Project Name from the dropdown items. Can you teach me how? I am not so familiar with Laravel. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the blade template you can loop options with below code

```php
<select name="project">
@foreach($projects as $project)
    <option value="{{ $project->id}" data-client="{{ $project->client_name }}">{{ $project->name }}</option>
@endforeah
</select>
```

And using click() method of jquery for get and display Client Name in textbox when you select a project in Dropbox.